# 30 rep points disappeared yesterday

Tags: support, reputation

30 points disappeared from my Rep yesterday. It was 902 when I went to bed, when I woke up yesterday AM it was 872. I checked the reputation, voting tabs, etc. and didn't see anything. No downvotes, no user dropped etc.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: lesson learned: abstain of answering of close- and delete-worthy questions. Regarding checks, do you have "show deleted posts" checkbox set in your profile page?

Comment: [more about "show removed posts" feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155999/show-removed-posts-in-reputation-history-by-default)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/31026/2322

This answer was deleted when the question "How to explain the experience I have gained in three years is greater than the time implies [closed]" was deleted; you had 30 rep from this question.

Here is the first part of this answer:

> 1) If you indeed have such a wealth of experience, list it in your resume. If you've done big things, tell about them, and apply for jobs you think are appropriate for your experience, as you assess it. Are you bound only to follow the instructions of a particular recruiter? **JUST DO IT - MARKET YOURSELF.** You don't have to sound like you're "the greatest thing since sliced bread", that will work against you, but don't be shy! And play it smart - if you're applying for a job that would pay $75k for someone with 7 years experience, discount yourself a bit, so someone will be more willing to give you a chance to prove yourself. And if you do get a call, back up your resume claims with knowledge - **strut your stuff** - and you just might get lucky and land that big job you want. I'm not acquainted with your entire situation, but I'd think that you have very little to lose and a great deal to gain by going that route.